How to implement Headlessjs in react native andriod using Kotlin
i want to implement Headless.js in my React Native application for android using Kotlin. And want to run the task after every 1 minute.
Here is my code
App.js

  import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import HeadlessTask from './HeadlessTask';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => HeadlessTask);




 MyTaskService.kt
    package com.limcee;

import android.content.Intent
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig

class MyTaskService : HeadlessJsTaskService() {
    override fun getTaskConfig(intent: Intent): HeadlessJsTaskConfig? {
        return intent.extras?.let {
            HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
                "SomeTaskName",
                Arguments.fromBundle(it),
                5000, // timeout for the task
                true // optional: defines whether or not the task is allowed in foreground.
                // Default is false
            )
        }
    }
}


AndroidManifest.xml   limcee is my package name
 <service android:name="com.limcee.MyTaskService" android:enabled="true" android:label="MyTaskService" />

//HeadlessTask
import {Alert} from 'react-native';

const HeadlessTask = async taskData => {
  // Handle your background task logic here
  console.log('Headless task started:', taskData);

  // Example: Show an alert in background
  Alert.alert('Background Task', 'Running in the background!');

  // IMPORTANT: Return a promise to indicate task completion
  return Promise.resolve();
};

export default HeadlessTask;

I've followed these steps, but I'm encountering issues with getting the background task (SomeTaskName) to run at the specified interval. Currently, it not working at all.
How can I ensure that my Headless.js task runs every minute in the background on Android using Kotlin in React Native? Are there any additional configurations or adjustments needed in my setup

Did you solve this?
